# Unable to preventDefault en Swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo esta funcion para agregar un clase para cuando se haga swipe

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.swiperight', function(event){  
  $(this).siblings().addClass("active");
  return false;         
});
```

funciona bien, pero me muestra este error por consola

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See

A que se debe?

Comment: Qué dice Google? Yo busqué y obtuve [algunas respuestas](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=what+are+passive+event+listeners). [Este link](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=what+are+passive+elements) tal vez te de más información.

Comment: Todo lo que sale en la consola no es necesariamente un error. Como consejo para cuidar la salud mental ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Había una vez unos listeners, pero los navegadores tuvieron que matarlos.

tl;dr: Ya en serio, eso es sólo un warning. Y lo podrías ignorar...

Versión larga: Lo que pasa es que estos listeners de scroll, wheel, swipe, condicionan fuertemente el desempeño del navegador cuando tiene que atender un evento de estos tipos.
Todos los navegadores modernos tienen una característica implementada que gestiona el scrolling usando hilos (¿ese tick que ofrece smooth scrolling?) para que la página se desplace suavemente incluso con JavaScript corriendo mientras eso pasa. Esta optimización termina por ser inútil en algunos casos que debe esperarse al resultado de cualquier handler de touchstart y touchmove, lo que puede resultar en que el evento scroll *se prevenga* completamente al llamar `preventDefault()` en el evento.

La solución básica es usar `{passive: true}` al definir el listener. A menos que estés usando JQuery, que entiendo que no tiene esa opción disponible.

Al marcar un listener de estos tipos como `passive` (pasivo), le prometes al navegador que el handler no va a llamar `preventDefault()` para deshabilitar el scrolling. Esto libera al navegador para responderle al evento de inmediato sin esperar a que la función JS responda.

Chrome, por ejemplo, sé que lo tiene habilitado por defecto, así que no tienes que hacer... nada. Simplemente te avisa que no está deteniendo el scrolling porque está tratando ese listener sobre el swipeleft, swiperight, como pasivo.

[Release notes de esta característica en Chrome](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/05/new-apis-to-help-developers-improve.html)

[Explicación detallada en inglés](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)

[Hilo en Jquery sobre soportar passive listeners](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871)

Comment: Muy buena aclaración, muchas gracias !!!